# Quantum gravity: should it stabilize inspirals?

Tags: string-theory, quantum-gravity, loop-quantum-gravity

Bohr model and Quantum Mechanics stabilize the atoms in order to have a minimum state (due to some effective or centrifugal force) avoiding electrons to hit the nuclei. Thus, electrons (accelerated charges) do not emit electromagnetic waves, losing energy until they fall down into the nucleus.

Quantum gravity: we know that classical gravity emitting GRAVITATIONAL waves, inspiral (just like classical atoms emitting electromagnetic waves), but...Shouldn't quantum gravity avoid this? That is, when (small) bodies theoretically approach Planck length, are they stabilized? Should we expect a similar stabilization from quantum gravity? What string theory says about this problem (2 particles, in strong gravity, with a radius when radiation and backreaction are important)? And LQG?

Comment: Well, when the Schwarzschild radius of a small black hole recedes behind its Compton  wavelength (at the Planck length, as you indicate) a workable consistent theory of gravity should strive to describe the system. You surely are not proposing a semi-realistic one such, are you?

Comment: No, but as string theory is generally considered finite (even SUGRA N=8 could be even finite), I was wondering if it (they) have a consistent answer of what happens with gravitational radiation just as Bohr model cheated and stated electrons were "stationary" and "non radiant" until QM was built. I mention string theory as I know the theory but, as far as I know, I have never seen an answer to this type of question (unless I missed some paper on gravitational wave emission and backreaction in string theory, another option).

Comment: Oh, if you wanted the analog Bohr-like radius of a semiclassical gravitational "atom" of a neutron and an electron, it would be *x* times *larger* than the Hydrogen atom Bohr radius, where $x\sim (m_{pl}^2/m_e m_n 137)\sim 2\cdot 10^{39}$.

Comment: Yes, that is part of my puzzle...Because it works for light particles as electrons or neutrons, not for massive particles...Take two very massive objects instead of elementary particles...I find the question  shocking... I know about gravitational atoms, I wrote about them in my blog...

Comment: I have trouble thinking of a stringy model of a purely gravitationally bound state of a small number of entities (massive D0-branes?), because other forces always come into play ("gravity is the weakest force").

Comment: The point is Mitchell Porter that whenever you want to answer what is a string made of, you return to the same point. What is fundamental in string theory if the own theory says strings are equivalent to (conformal) fields in space-time? What are p-branes if "they are fundamental" in general? What is vibrating? The notion of space-time itself and particle-ness, due to duality, vanish. So, what is a string/D0-brane/Dp-brane if looked with another high energy probe (another brane)? Of course, some people will say they are made of nothing, since they are "fundamental", but that is not an answer.

Comment: Thought experiment: imagine a very high energy graviton (irrespectly what a graviton is, or can't we do this without saying that gravitons are excitations of a quantum or pre-quantum space-time?). Accelerated masses do emit gravitons, that includes strings and branes. Well, is the emission of gravitons stopped at some point? Quantum theory suggest that! Otherwise, we have to accept everything will decay into nothingless, even space-time itself, made of "stuff"...If we support the idea that strings are the ultimate blocks, how can it affect the picture?

Comment: You know Strominger's recent work on emission of soft (zero-energy) photons? That also applies to gravitons. And the answer for photons seems to be, that the true asymptotic states are not e.g. bare electrons, but electrons dressed with photons. So maybe there needs to be some kind of gravitational dressing of asymptotic states.

Comment: I have issues understanding "soft-gravitons", "soft-photons" in general. Zero energy bosons are puzzling...Because of the uncertainty principle! Physically, zero energy bosons are impossible due to quantum fluctuations...And however, I find the concept of asymptotic symmetry (present even in Hawking's thesis unexplictly!) challenging!